# How to do something after video finishes?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a 15 second video that's not embedded (it's sourced from an url). How can I get it to play the next frame when then video is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`VideoEvent.COMPLETE`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/VideoEvent.html#COMPLETE) which is dispatched when a video has finished playing.

```
video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, _doNext);
function _doNext(e:VideoEvent):void
{
    video.removeEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, _doNext);
    trace("video done, what's next?");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the FLVPlayback component, you can do it like this:

```
// for clarification
var video:FLVPlayback = myVideoInstance;

video.source = "http://example.com/myvideo.flv";
video.autoPlay = true;
video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, function(e:VideoEvent) {
    // video has finished
});
```